# Why does this give me a segfault

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to write a hello world program but it doesn't work - why?

```
.data
    str:
        .ascii "Hello World\12\0"
.text
    .globl main
    .extern printf
    main:
        pushq %rbp
        movq %rsp,%rbp
        movq str,%rdi
        callq printf
        movq %rbp,%rsp
        popq %rbp
        ret
```

Comment: You should use `movabsq $str, %rdi` to load the address. What you did was load the first 8 bytes of the string which then poor `printf` tried to use as address and faulted. Also, you need to zero `%al` before the `call`.

Comment: Maybe the assembler is finding it as hard to read as we are.

Comment: @Jester `mov $str,%rdi` is sufficient as the ABI places data and code within the first two gigabytes of the address space.

Comment: @fuz: `mov $str, %edi` is even better, of course, since GNU `as` doesn't optimize the 7-byte sign-extended mov-immediate into a 5-byte zero-extended mov-immediate.

Comment: To format code, don't use `<code>`, select the code and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: Make sure you follow initially course information/tutorial for your target platform + assembler syntax (ie. gas + 64b clib in this case). And gas syntax is IMO a bit harder to read/write for humans as Intel syntax, so you will have to pay extra attention to all those weird symbols everywhere, like if `$` is ahead of number or not, making it completely different instruction. Once you are somewhat familiar with basics and fully understand how your instructions work in the CPU, you can easily pick different syntax/platform examples for inspiration, but initially they will just confuse you.

Answer (score 0):

You are violating the calling convention. Since this is 64-bit code running on Linux, the applicable calling convention would be [System V AMD64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI). (More detailed info in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.)

Note that for variadic functions like `printf`, this calling convention requires that the caller set the `RAX` register to indicate the number of floating-point arguments being passed in vector registers. You do not initialize the `RAX` register, so it effectively contains garbage data. The `printf` function then tries to read an undefined number of floating-point values from vector registers, and thus causes a segmentation fault.

All you need to do to fix the code is to zero-out `RAX` before making the call. There are several ways to do that. The obvious is `movq  $0, %rax`, however, a more optimal way to zero-out a register is to use the `XOR` instruction—*e.g.*: `xorq  %rax, %rax`. But you can do even better than that. Since on x86-64, all instructions implicitly clear the upper 32 bits of the destination register, you can simply do `xorl  %eax, %eax`. This is one byte shorter, and will execute slightly faster.

Technically, your `main` function should also be returning 0. The calling convention specifies that a function returns an integer result using the `RAX` register, so you just need to zero-out `RAX` again before you return. Right now, `printf` is returning its result in `RAX`, and since you don't set `RAX`, you are effectively returning the result of `printf` from `main`. That's legal, but probably not what you want.

So, your `main` function should look like this:

```
  pushq  %rbp
  movq   %rsp, %rbp
  movq   str,  %rdi
  xorl   %eax, %eax
  callq  printf
  xorl   %eax, %eax
  movq   %rbp, %rsp
  popq   %rbp
  ret
```

But you can make the code even shorter by eliminating the `movq  %rsp, %rbp` instruction. You aren't doing `RBP`-relative addressing, so you don't need that here. And, [as Peter Cordes pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403678/why-does-this-give-me-a-segfault#comment70011931_41403678), you could optimize `movq  str, %rdi` to `movl  str, %edi`. Your final code would then simply be:

```
  pushq  %rbp         # reserve 8 bytes of space on the stack
  movl   str,  %edi   # get address of string constant
  xorl   %eax, %eax   # clear RAX register in preparation for calling printf
  callq  printf
  xorl   %eax, %eax   # clear RAX register so we return 0
  popq   %rbp         # clean up the stack
  ret
```

Comment: `movq   str,  %rdi` loads 8 bytes from the string, that's the primary cause of printf segfaulting (unless the OP had an old libc that used AL for a computed jump, instead of just 0 / non-0 check to save all the XMM regs).  You want `mov  $str,  %edi` or `lea str(%rip), %rdi` to pass a pointer to the label.